# Vertex shader doesn't work well with cloned objects

Tags: opengl, glsl, vertex-shader, opengl-3

I'm using OpenGL to create a sphere (approximation):

I'm "inflating" the triangle to create an eight of a sphere:

[image]

[image]

I'm then drawing that octant four times, and each time rotating the model transoformation by 90°, to achieve a hemisphere:

[image]

Code related to drawing calls:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    model_trans = glm::rotate(model_trans, glm::radians(i * 90.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(uniform_model, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model_trans));
    glDrawElementsBaseVertex(GL_TRIANGLES, sizeof(sphere_indices) / sizeof(sphere_indices[0]),
                             GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0, (sizeof(grid_vertices)) / (ATTR_COUNT * sizeof(GLfloat)));
}
```

My goal is to color each vertex based on the angle of its projection in the XY-plane. Since I'm normalizing values, the resulting projection should behave like an trigonometric circle, x value being the cosine value of the angle with the positive end of x-axis. And because the cosine is an continuous function, my sphere should have continual color, too. However, it is not so:

[image]

Is this issue caused by cloning the object? That's the only thing I can think of, but it shouldn't matter, since the vertex shader only receives individual vertices. Speaking of which, here is my vertex shader:

```
#version 150 core

in vec3 position;
/* flat : the color will be sourced from the provoking vertex. */
flat out vec3 Color;

/* transformation matrices */
uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

void main() {

    gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(position, 1.0);

    vec3 vector_proj = vec3(position.x, position.y, 0.0);
    normalize(vector_proj);
    /* Addition and division only for mapping range [-1, +1] to [0, 1] */
    float cosine = (vector_proj.x + 1) / 2;
    Color = vec3(cosine);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to calculate the color associated to the vertex from the world coordinate of the vertex position.

`position` is the model coordinate, but not the world coordinate. You have to apply the model matrix to `position` to transform from model space to world space, before calculating `vector_proj`:

```
vec4 world_pos = model * vec4(position, 1.0);

vec3 vector_proj = vec3( world_pos.xy, 0.0 );
```

---

The parameter to [`normalize`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/normalize.xhtml) is not an in-out parameter. It is an input parameter, the normalized result is returned from the function:

```
vector_proj = normalize(vector_proj);
```

---

You can simplify the code as follows:

```
void main()
{
    vec4 world_pos = model * vec4(position, 1.0);
    gl_Position = projection * view * world_pos;

    vec2 vector_proj = normalize(world_pos.xy);

    /* Addition and division only for mapping range [-1, +1] to [0, 1] */
    float cosine = (vector_proj.x + 1) / 2;
    Color = vec3(cosine);
}
```

Comment: That was beautiful. Thank you!